Prove $f(n) = 10^n-(5+\sqrt{17})^n-(5-\sqrt{17})^n$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$ for all positive integer.
Problem:$f(n) = 10^n-(5+\sqrt{17})^n-(5-\sqrt{17})^n$ is a function which is valid for all integers $n\geq1$. Prove that $f(n)$ is always perfectly divisible by $2^{n+1}$.
My attempt: I found this question here. I read the question and the answers. All contains induction or recurrence. I want to solve it with binomial theorem. I expanded two brackets and that went brutal.
Conclusion: Also, do not use modular arithmetic. I want to solve it with only binomial theorem and high school tools. Help me.

You should write a recurrence relation for $f(n+2)$ in terms of $f(n+1)$ and $f(n)$ and do this by induction. No need to work with the explicit formula.

Why not modular arithmetic, like even or odd? This is very elementary (see Bill's answer).

Because, I don't like to use modular arithmetic. I hope, there is a way.

Replace use of a power sum recurrence by use of the Binomial theorem in this answer in the dupe. Then the inductive step in the proof that $,a^n+b^n = (a+b)^n + k, ab,$ for some integer $,k,$ is e.g. as below
$$\begin{align} (a+b)^7 &= a^7+b^7 + 7ab\color{#0a0}{(a^5+b^5}) + 21(ab)^2(\color{#0a0}{a^3+b^3}) + 35(ab)^3(\color{#0a0}{a^1+b^1})\
&= a^7+b^7 +j:! ab,\ \ \text{for some integer } j \end{align}\qquad$$
since by strong induction all $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ terms are integers (using $,a+b,, ab,$ are integers). $\ \ $
